# Set parent menu item and child sub menu item to active based on URL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have some code I'm using for a side navigation menu that works in the main how I require.

There are two sidebar menus one on each side of a three column layout. The sidebar to the right hierarchically is the main menu and resides in an ASP.NET MasterPage. This menu sets its menu item to active (CSS) based on the URL.

The sidebar to the left is a sub menu which resides in an ASP.NET NestedMasterPage this also sets its menu item to active.

So the parent nav and the child nav should both be in an active state at the same time. However when I select a parent menu item which has a child menu item on the left only one menu state (at present the child) is active.

I know this has something to do with the URL but I'm not sure how to solve the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = location.href.toLowerCase();

    $("#menu1 li a").each(function () {
        if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {


            $("li.active").removeClass("active");

            $(this).parent().addClass("active");

        }

    });


    $("#menu2 li a").each(function () {
        if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {

            $("li.active").removeClass("active");

            $(this).parent().addClass("active");

        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = location.href.toLowerCase();

    $("#menu1 li a").each(function () {
        if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {


            $("#menu1 li.active").removeClass("active");

            $(this).parent().addClass("active");

        }

    });


    $("#menu2 li a").each(function () {
        if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {

            $("#menu2 li.active").removeClass("active");

            $(this).parent().addClass("active");

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: The main side navigation menu nearly works the way I desire. When I click on the main navigation and arrive at a page were there is a sub navigation both navigations are highlighted. However when I select any link other than the top link of that sub navigation the main side navigation jumps back to the top menu item in the structure. I need the main side navigation to remain were it is whilst selecting all the menu items in the sub navigation.

Comment: Can you do a jsFiddle and share with us? It will make easier for us to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using parentsUntil('topmenu')

```
$(this).parentsUntil('topmenu').addClass("active");
```